# Differential equation for a raindrop

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am learning differential equations using *Single Variable Calculus* by James Stewart. I was stuck by the 49th question in section 9.3, page 626. Here is the question

> When a raindrop falls, it increases in size and so its mass at
>   time *t* is a function of *t*, namely *m(t)*. The rate of growth of the
>   mass *km(t)* is for some positive constant *k*. When we apply
>   New ton’s Law of Motion to the raindrop, we get *(mv)'= gm*,
>   where *v* is the velocity of the raindrop (directed downward) and *g*
>   is the acceleration due to gravity. The terminal velocity of the
>   raindrop is *lim(t->∞)v*. Find an expression for the terminal
>   velocity in terms of *k* and *g*.

And here is the provided solution:

[image]

I wonder why the equation in the first line of the solution:
*mv' + m'v = gm* 
make sence?

I think *mv' = gm*, so does it means that *m'v = 0*?

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, Newton's law works in terms of $$\vec F=\frac {d\vec p}{dt}$$ where $\vec F$ is the resulting external force and $\vec p$ is momentum.

The expression for momentum writes $m\vec v$, where $m$ is the mass and $\vec v$ is the speed. In most cases the mass is constant, hence we simplify $\frac {d\vec p}{dt}=m\frac {d\vec v}{dt}$.

However, in your case mass is not constant, so we are forced to use the equation $$\vec F=m(t)\frac {d\vec v(t)}{dt}+\frac {dm(t)}{dt}\vec v.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I've get the point. :)